# Android - objectAnimator xml alpha animation not working

Tags: android, xml, vector, alpha, objectanimator

Using `alpha` as the `propertyName` of the `objectAnimator` does nothing at all. The `objectAnimator` is connected to a `path` inside the `vector`.

fading_animator.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="700"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/>
</set>
```

animated_vector.xml:

```
<animated-vector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable">

  <target
    android:name="pathTarget"
    android:animation="@animator/fading_animator"/>

</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When trying to animate the alpha of a path, you have to use either `fillAlpha` or `strokeAlpha`. Similarly, `scaleX` and `scaleY` will not work on a `path` but it will work on a `group` inside the `vector`.